# Chart Validation

Tags: c#, .net, excel, powerpoint

I'm gonna make a project to convert data and chart to powerpoint file to excel file.

but I found some problem here,,

I have make a project to convert chart, with this script

> public static void GetChart(string strFilePath, string strDestPath)
>           {
>
> ```
>         xl.Application xlApp;
>         xl.Workbook xlWorkBook;
>         xl.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
>         object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
>
>         xlApp = new xl.ApplicationClass();
>         xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFilePath, 0, true, 5,
> ```
>
> "", "", true,
>                   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,
>   "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
>               xlWorkSheet =
>   (xl.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
>               xl.ChartObjects xlCharts =
>   (xl.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
>               xl.ChartObject myChart = (xl.ChartObject)xlCharts.Item(1);
>               xl.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

and then I convert it into an image with this script

> GetChart(@"" + textBox1.Text + "", @"d:\" + textBox2.Text + ".jpeg");
>                   label5.Text = @"D:\" + textBox2.Text + ".jpeg";
>
> ```
>             pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"" + label5.Text +
> ```
>
> "");

but I think not all of excel file contains a chart, so I try to search a validation about how to detect a chart in every excel file.

How should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the number of items in the charts collection, ie xlCharts.Count